# Can't read more than eight bytes from serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, byte

I'm working in c programming language under Linux, trying to create a communication application with serial port. The program is sending data to a serial port and reading received data from a microcontroller. The received data could reach any number of bytes between 10 and 64 but no more and no less. I use the following code to read and write data:

```
unsigned char send_bytes[] = { 0x1, 0x6, 0x2, 0xAA, 0x2, 0x3, 0xB8, 0x4 };

int w = write(fd, send_bytes, sizeof(send_bytes)); // send

char buffer[64];

int r = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); //read data
```

My problem is that `r` never gets more than 8 bytes of data. Does anyone know why is this the case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int read`, Use different name for function and variable. Don't mix them.

Comment: Sorry they are not named the same. I wrote it here like that, it's fixed now.

Comment: Try adding subsequent `read` functions and see what they return.

Comment: You probably need to show your code for the `open()` and initialization of the serial port.  Also, performing syscalls in the variable declarations in not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your operating system is only providing 8 bytes of serial port buffering, so it "favors" to deliver incoming data in chunks of 8 bytes.

Repeat the read for as long as it has data available. You can use `select()` for this on systems where it's available.

Also, since the other end is a microcontroller which might be slower than your workstation by a large margin, perhaps the data simply isn't available yet when you do the `read()`. That's another reason to try again, of course.

Comment: I'm using 64 bit operating system, so it's ok to read 8 bytes at a time, but when I try to loop trough data it gives them wrong.

Comment: @user2081328 I'm sorry, but that doesn't make any sense. This is not a matter of whether your platform is 64-bit or not. And "it gives them wrong" is not very precise so it's hard to help based on that.

Comment: Microcontroller sends bytes in specific order and program can read and interpret them. When I read data in windows in C# program that I have made, it gives me entire stream of bytes in correct order, but when I try to do this in linux it gives me only first eight bytes. When I tried to loop and repeat reading first eight bytes are correct but others are not, they don't make any sense. I know that it is reading bytes because program blocks when there is nothing to read on port.